# SWT FileDialog does not work correctly on Mac OSX with Oracle Java 7

Tags: java, swt, osx-mountain-lion, java-7

It seems file chooser dialogs are not working properly with SWT on Mac OSX 64-bit, with Oracle Java 7:

```
FileDialog dlg = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.OPEN);
dlg.open();
```

One major problem is that file previews (the right-most pane that appears when selecting a file) does not work: the spinner does not stop, CPU usage increases. Randomly, another issue is that folder contents appear empty.

Everything works fine with the official Apple Java 6 package. I tried several several versions of SWT (4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.3, the beta 4.4 builds as well).

Is anybody aware of a workaround? Could this be fixed at the SWT level, or is it a Java 7 issue?

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue also. 
It appears to be a direct combination of the following (Java 7, Eclipse 3.7.2, and OSX 10.9)

I found this explanation: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=420682 (Bug 420682 - In Indigo, Open File dialog only appears once in OS X Mavericks (10.9) )

I hope this helps you, but the basic message is as follows:

- either upgrade to 4.x based RCP bundles, or at least 3.8.x
- don't use Java 7 (I don;t recommend that one)

Comment: I resolved my issue upgrading Eclipse to 3.8.2, but, unfortunately, i had to revert everything to 3.7 because of problems with BIRT editor. i saw a "code" workaround in eclipse bugs somewhere, but i cannot locate it anymore... i really need to implement this fix.

Comment: I experience this bug with Java 6, the official Apple version.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the core of the issue is the -XstartOnFirstThread Java flag. One hack is to avoid using this flag, and implement the associated behavior (ie, starting SWT on the first thread) yourself.

Fortunately, a very helpful Eclipse contributor - Silenio Quarti - has done so, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389486#c5.
Caveat: To be integrated in a non-Mac IDE, this source needs to be refactored, and all references to org.eclipse.swt.internal.** must be done through reflection.

Until Oracle and/or Apple fix the SDK version 7, this is the best and only workaround I've found thus far.

Comment: I have the same problem, but avoiding to use -XstartOnFirstThread is not possible, because I don't use it. Any other suggestions?
What's strange is, that if I start my Application from Eclipse, this problem doesn't happen. Only after having packed it into a Mac OS X .app using the AppBundler, it appears. Mac Lion, Java 7.